# codeigniter session Security warning

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image]

a session error coming in codeignter any one help me what is this .

config file code:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: `$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';` code already there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in config file add this code

```
 $config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

to

```
 $config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

or

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
```

Comment: Not really a good answer ;) explain WHY the error is being triggered is more interesting ;) Altho this may be the solution

Comment: this above code already there?